# Self Answer Questions being too broad

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, self-answer, needs-more-focus, instant-self-answer

I'm planning to do another self-answer Q&A style question, but I just had a thought that if I came across this question asked in the wild without an answer, I would flag to close as too broad. However, since I am giving an in-depth answer to my own question would you VTC and why?

The question at the moment is:

What is the minimum amount of configuration that I need for Hibernate 4 with Spring 3 XML configuration and annotation based transaction management? Also, what are some of the common Hibernate options?

I'm open to changing it to avoid the dreaded VTC.

Edit 1: I'm changing the actual question to narrow it down to just Hibernate 4 configuration. The question now reads:

Assuming that I've already got a working Spring project how do I then add in Hibernate 4 with Spring 3 XML configuration? I want to use annotation based transaction management and have my objects mapped using annotations.

Comment: It seems more appropriate for a blog post.

Comment: If the question meets criteria to for a close vote, I'll vote it - regardless of how popular it is, how old it is or who has answered it. I'd vote to close this question (too broad).

Comment: Thats what people said about my last one. Only problem is I don't have a blog and I wanted a SO resource to point to when people ask the question "My Project doesn't work, and I don't know why" and then flagging it as no code provided. The third reason, is that I see so many people saying "I'm following tutorial X and Y isn't working". Upon looking at the tutorial, I find its 3 years old, and totally out of date. I am planning to keep updating this post as new versions come out.

Comment: Sounds like a community wiki post to me.

Comment: For those interested I did post the question, you can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422678/how-can-i-set-up-hibernate-4-with-spring-3-config-xmls

Comment: @JamesMassey Whether the question is off-topic or not, you should spend some time learning about the site's markdown.  Your syntax highlighting is off, and your multi-line code block in a list six separate lines rather than a code block.  `<!-- language: xml -->` before a code block, or `<!-- language-all: xml -->` will help.  Right now you're highlighting your XML as though it were Java, which looks pretty bad.

Comment: Oops, how embarrassing, I totally missed that. I'll fix it tomorrow, kinda hard on my phone

Comment: @JamesMassey You don't need a note like: "Note: This is a self-answer Q&A style question intended to give a canonical answer to a common problem. I intend to expand this question over time to keep up to date with Hibernate."  The question should stand on its own.  It shouldn't matter who is answering is, or why.  If you have to [apologize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apologetics) for the form of your question or answer, then it should probably be improved instead.

Comment: Well originally I didn't have that, and my question got 2 down votes within 5 minutes, because the question looked like the typical 'gimme teh codez' question that is endemic on the Hibernate tag. So I added it and i didn't get any more down votes until an hour ago. People didn't bother to actually read the answer, they just down vote the question. It shouldn't matter, but it does. But I take your point about spending the time improving the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What's wrong with the question

What's not good is the subquestion: "What are common options?" this is clearly too broad.

I would recommend to narrow it further down to include some of the scheme that you want to show. Like: "What is the minimal configuration necessary ... for the scenario of only one Entity with the attributes..." or something the like.

### How I would vote

I don't think its too broad. It has a very significant element that makes it narrow enough: It asks for the "minimal" amount. So there can be one correct answer to this and it is the one that uses the least items.

Sure that answer still has to be quite long and all, but completeness doesn't make it wrong.