# Can I turn a blog post into an SO question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I've seen [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266971/can-i-post-so-questions-and-answers-in-a-personal-blog) on whether or not it's acceptable to turn SO questions into blog posts, but I can't seem to find anything on the reverse relationship, so here it goes:

I am currently writing a post for my company's blog that deals with a programming situation that I think not that many people know what to do in, and could really help people who get stuck. Given that my company's blog is probably not going to pop up during Google searches for that topic, I wanted to know if, after I've completed the post, it would be acceptable to post a question (and immediately answer it in true "share your knowledge, Q&A style") on SO as well.

Would something like that be OK? Would it be more acceptable if I don't put a link to the company's blog in either the question or the answer (just to make sure that no one thinks that I'm trying to promote it or myself)? Are there any other tips that I should be aware of when doing this?

The post would be a general programming one, and not have anything to do with my company's products.

Comment: "Would it be more acceptable if I don't put a link to the company's blog in either the question or the answer?" Yes, I think that would make it more acceptable.

Comment: I did something that [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/164043/31260). The only thing I missed is that I dropped an answer into a close-worthy, [too-broad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261616/self-answer-questions-being-too-broad) question (I just didn't know back then). Hope you'll make a better question to land your answer at

Comment: Just don't make it a fluff piece. Get to the point.

Comment: @Peter: Changing SO to Stack Overflow is absolutely pointless...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Absolutely, self-answer away! Incidentally, I remember reading that this was an intended use of the self-answer feature.

But, make sure to follow the rules:

- The question needs to be an appropriate, high-quality Stack Overflow question. If this is a *long* blog post, it could easily be too broad.
- The answer needs to be a high-quality Stack Overflow answer. I'm going to guess you won't have trouble with this one.
- If the post is *about* your product, make sure to disclose your affiliation. If it's about programming in general, you shouldn't need to worry. Basically, check yourself against the self-promotion rules.

Comment: The post will be on the longer side only because I'd be explaining it in more detail, whereas any SO question would obviously have a more simplified version of the situation.

Comment: Should I also link to the blog post, or would that reek too much of self-promotion?

Comment: @IronMan84 Its a pretty easy test. If you (or I) came across the question *randomly*, would we consider it high quality? If so, go ahead, if not, you need to refine it a bit. I'd link to the post (along with your summary in the answer of course) and disclose that you wrote it.

Comment: In addition, make sure that the answer you post contains sufficient detail **here** to be useful if your linked site is unavailable for some reason in the future. The link should be to *additional information*, but the answer should be self-contained so that it remains useful even without the external info.

Comment: In addition, it should not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify your *programming situation* that you want to write about. Depending on what it actually is, it may not be a good fit for SO. You could look into [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if it fits better there, but then it probably wouldn't get as much traffic.