# Providing a follow-up link for an SO answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Background:
I recently answered a question on SO with a suggested solution if their target platform was Windows (we had the same situation as OP several years ago).  OP followed up in comments that unfortunately they needed a cross-platform solution.  It so happens that our old solution (suggested to OP) now also needs to be cross-platform, so I put together a proof-of-concept and drafted an answer for OP outlining the basics with enough detail that they should have no problem writing their own.  I'm fairly far along with fleshing out a complete implementation that will be released as open source but there are two issues: 1) it's too much code for an appropriate SO answer, 2) I can't release open source for this under a CC license anyway as it is not an "approved" (e.g. BSD) license in this case.

Situation:
I'd like to inform OP (or anyone else interested) that an open-source package solution will be available for this and how to access it by referencing a blog address in my post.  This will be through my personal blog, so there is absolutely no commercial interest/promotion/whatever.  In a way, it's somewhat similar to this: [Can I turn a blog post into an SO question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278388/can-i-turn-a-blog-post-into-an-so-question?cb=1), except I'm not self-answering.

My draft answer looks roughly like this:

> complete code not posted, but here's how you can do it.
>    blah blah blah, all the info you need to write it yourself with this approach
>    ...
>    if you don't want to write it yourself, will be posted as open source, address is in my profile

NB: I have zero interest in SO as a "connection with another human" (as Shog9 puts it here, in ["Stack Overflow is not a large community"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084)), but rather am asking in the sense of "a venue in which [to] share information" (same link).  Basically, if someone thinks what I'll be posting somewhere will save them some time, great - now they know where to find it; if not, also fine.  I have to finish it either way, and many developers use SO as a productivity tool, not just as a Q&A site in the narrower sense.

**Question:**
What is the appropriate protocol in this situation - is it frowned upon to provide a link to code *that will be released by the answerer* that is either too long for SO or can't be released under creative commons license, and
if so, why/how does this differ from providing a pointer to any other open source code or resource?

It goes without saying that I mean "non-commercial, I don't want to contact you, HTH but YMMV" situations here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broad lines of your approach look fine to me. If you want to go as far as providing executable code that won't fit in an answer, then, at a minimum, explain the key points of your solution *in your answer*. This is what you plan to do.

However, I would **not** say this in my answer:

> if you don't want to write it yourself, will be posted as open source, address is in my profile

I would wait until the code is ready to mention it *or* leave the note out of the answer but include a comment under the answer that mentions the upcoming code, then when the code is ready, I'd add the link (and remove the comment, if I used one).

Sending someone through your profile to get the code just rubs me the wrong way. Even if there is no self-serving intent behind it, it's just one extra level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks, a follow-on comment (with subsequent add link comment, delete original comment) seems like a good approach.

Comment: FWIW, based on feedback in the accepted answer, here's what I ended up with (as of this comment, before follow-up addition of code): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284217/turning-a-folder-into-a-single-file-without-zipping-it/27340791#27340791.  

As SO has had a chance to chew on the accepted answer for my question for a few days with no detractors, I'll probably use the same approach in the future for similar situations.

Comment: oops, make that "before...addition of *link to* code..."