# Creating the Windows 10 calendar in VBA Excel: can we allow broad and useful "canonical" self-answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical, needs-more-focus, instant-self-answer

This is concerning the question: [How can I create the Windows 10 calendar in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54650417/5223757)

This question has 4 close-votes and a lot of upvotes. It is a self-answer that appears broad… until you realise that [the VBA calendar widget doesn't always exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493134/5223757) (there's a VB6 one, but not VBA). This question, while written a little like a blog post, is about how to reliably add a date-picker to a VBA form; the answer provides code to do so.

This is something that I expect to be asked several times – and in fact it has, though not in this way and not with such an answer.

Is this allowed?

Comment: At first glance, that question can be boiled down to, "How do I recreate this thing?"  It shows no attempts, no reason why it's needed, or why existing functionality does not meet the needs.  I'd certainly lean to that being too broad.

Comment: @fbueckert "This is to help the VBA community which unfortunately doesn't have a **free** control at their disposal to incorporate into their projects. The only ones which we can use require registering mscal.ocx or mscomct2.ocx as mentioned in the link below." And this is a self-answer; it does provide an attempt; that attempt is full enough to be an answer itself.

Comment: Er.  Am I missing something here?  VBA *has* a datepicker; it shows up on date fields, in Access at least.  It doesn't work exactly like the W10 calendar, but it doesn't change the fact that a date picker exists.

Comment: An attempt to solve the problem has to be *in the question*.  Otherwise, it turns into a requirements dump question, which is generally going to be too broad.  That's what the question itself looks like.

Comment: The second answer there is most definitely NAA, it is an extended comment on the first answer.

Comment: @BrakNicku Wiki lock then. But not closure.

Comment: There's no such thing as a wiki lock.  Do you mean community wiki?  That's not a, "Get out of jail free" card; questions still have to meet standards, wiki or no wiki.

Comment: It looks more like a blog post about how to do something then a question seeking an answer.

Comment: @fbueckert There is a wiki lock. But yeah, it probably should be closed.

Comment: Oh, so just locking it.  Why?  What is it about this question that deserves that treatment?

Comment: @fbueckert It's a special type of lock that just disables adding new answers, while not counting towards a question ban for the asker.

Comment: They've got over 100k.  They're not going to be question banned.

Comment: @fbueckert: VBA has a Datepicker? Since when? Have you ever worked with VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes.  In fact, I have it open right now.  That's the point I'm making; there *is* a calendar.

Comment: @fbueckert Have you got a 32-bit version of Office?

Comment: @fbueckert: Then you are mistaken. It is not a VBA control. It is a VB6 control which is not freely distributable. You need to register mscal.ocx or mscomct2.ocx  :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout See, that's important information to add to the question itself.  I work with VBA day in and day out, and that's not something that I'd know.  To me, the question seems to be solving a problem that's already been solved.

Comment: `@SiddharthRout See, that's important information to add to the question itself. I work with VBA day in and day out, and that's not something that I'd know. To me, the question seems to be solving a problem that's already been solved. – fbueckert 35 secs ago` @fbueckert: Then please go and re-read the question... What you are asking for is already mentioned there...

Comment: Would this question be acceptable if it wasn't a self answered question?

Comment: Should the question be edited? Yes. Closed? No.

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, it doesn't.  I don't have *either* of the controls registered you are mentioning in my project.  The closest I have is MSCOMCTL.OCX, so please, stop with the condescension.

Comment: @fbueckert: mscal.ocx , mscomct2.ocx, MSCOMCTL.OCX are vb6 controls. Yes I have mentioned 2 and not the 3rd one but that doesn't change a thing :) And no I am not trying to put you down. I am amused at the way how people want to close it as "Too Broad"

Comment: Such questions and answers are no more allowed or not allowed than any other question/answer. The fact that it's a self answer is irrelevant. Judge the question/answer on it's usefulness/quality, not on how it was created or by who.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Then...maybe clarify the problem statement properly?  The community is signalling there's an issue that needs resolution; rather than discount that, can it hurt to try to resolve the issues they're pointing out?

Comment: @fbueckert: Oh I am always ready to help but besides the downvotes and closed votes (Too Broad?), did you see anyone pointing out apt criticism that I could incorporate?

Comment: @Siddharth As I said at the begining, it seems like a requirements dump. That is my bet on why it got too broad votes.

Comment: _"An attempt to solve the problem has to be in the question. Otherwise, it turns into a requirements dump"_ On the other hand, including an attempt turns it into a debugging question. If there's an issue here, it's not "doesn't show the code", it's the size of the task.

Comment: Related: [Can I turn a blog post into an SO question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278388/can-i-turn-a-blog-post-into-an-so-question)

Comment: Also related: [_"close reasons are means, and not ends"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364947/603977)

Comment: Also also related: [_"Does this post make Stack Overflow (and by extension, the Internet) a better or worse place?"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379967/603977)

Comment: @fbueckert Access forms are not VBA UserForms, they're owned by the Access host; from the VBE's standpoint they are document modules just like a Worksheet module is in Excel. VBA does not have a datepicker control, you are conflating the Access form designer and its Access-specific controls with VBA.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Maybe you should edit it to include some busted code that you'd copied from a forum that's been irrelevant for 20 years and change the title to "I need codez for calendar. Can you fix this?"  That's apparently perfectly on-topic these days on the [vba] tag... </sarcasm> Seriously, this post is a *ton* better than most of the questions in the tag.

Comment: I have updated the question in the related link. Hope it makes more sense now as to why is that post important...

Comment: being "important" doesn't make it immune to falling under the provided close reasons.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, welcome to the new 'friendlier' StackOverflow.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've edited my first answer; please review and reconsider that checkmark: a recent post (linked) has seriously shaken my stance on this subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I turn a blog post into an SO question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278388/can-i-turn-a-blog-post-into-an-so-question)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've flagged my own Q+A post to get a historical lock, which is now in effect. When I wrote this answer I failed to see the [glaring loophole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380173/1188513) in this stance, and to be honest I don't think there's a solution to this problem that can make everyone happy. I'm thinking the "Post Q+A" feature itself might be the problem, I don't know. In light of a *reductio ad absurdum* counter-example of a <1K rep user posting a Q+A where the "question" is absurdingly irrelevant, I'm finding myself in complete agreement with the idea that *any* question on SO should be *reasonably answerable* by anyone coming across that question with the knowledge to answer it.

In other words, I don't think "here's how you do X" Q+A posts that are effectively *too broad* in nature, are a good fit for SO (hence my lock request on my own Q+A post). Note that this does not take anything away from the usefulness/value of such posts: I genuinely believe there is tremendous value in this calendar code, but upon reflection allowing it on SO is indeed unfair.

That leaves [this rather unpopular option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380164/1188513) as, in my [fully biased](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/vba/topusers) opinion, the only sensible solution: working code that's open to feedback on any/all aspects, including alternative implementations and other enhancements, *exactly* fits the [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), SO's smaller sister site, which happens to have more than double SO's 30K character limit for posts, since very long Q&As are very frequent over there.

*Original unchanged post follows (+31/-8 as of this revision); I would delete this answer, but it being the top-voted answer here *and* bearing the OP's checkmark makes me reluctant to do this.*

---

There's a major difference between what we see every day ("How can I do X?", or "I need code that does XYZ, pretty please!"), and what happened here.

Instant self-answers such as this one, are not posted with the same state of mind at all.

Accepting a canonical "how do I do X?" Q&A from a 100K user isn't favoritism or elitism or whatever-you-want-to-call-it-ism. It's common sense.

If a 100K user asks a "how do I do X?" question *without it being instant self-answered*, then it should be closed as *too broad* just like every other "how do I do X?" only-answerable-with-a-tutorial question we see (and correctly vote to close) every day.

Stack Overflow wants to build a **repository of useful questions and answers that make the Internet a better place**, and this is *exactly* what this post would do, if the SO community would let it.

"How do I do X?" questions are *too broad* to be reasonably answerable: "too broad" doesn't mean "off-topic" (if it does then the vote-to-close dialog has major UX issues), it means it's not reasonable to expect experts to spend several hours of their own time *for free*, to provide a solution. So we VTC and comment-link to some tutorials or other resources when we can, because we're kind, well-meaning and welcoming.

If *the expert themselves* has already spent the time and effort and wants to share their knowledge with the world on the wonderful platform that is Stack Overflow, then who are we to say "eh you can't do that, it's not fair to the 1-rep users that ask similar questions *and expect someone else to answer them*".

I'm not advocating for anyone to turn SO into some blogging platform, but shutting down self-answered questions like that is:

- Frustrating major contributors that *want* to share stuff - this isn't being done for Internet points (and even if it were, then what?);
- Frustrating thousands of would-be viewers that could have learned from it;
- Moving valuable knowledge outside of SO, off to some obscure blog with a fraction of the viewership;
- Throwing the baby with the bath water, conflating two MASSIVELY unrelated reasons for posting ("here's how you can do X", vs "gimmeh teh codez plz! urgent!!!");
- Preventing other valuable contributions (answers) from other experts that come across the Q&A and think "hmm I'd do *this* instead".

How's that a win exactly?

Instant self-answers, whether they're posted by a 100K rep or a 1-rep user, are not *too broad*. Sharing knowledge is the very essence of this site, regardless of your rep score. That's what brought me here, and that's what's keeping me here.

Comment: I'm glad that you have reconsidered your stance.  While I agree the question provides quite a bit of value, I had trouble reconciling that with how we can consistently curate such content.  There's some inconsistency inherent in the system, but we can try to make it as consistent as possible.

Comment: I believe you were right the first time. The _reductio_ can be halted by applying basic judgement and discrimination. That's the core of moderation here: _is this good, or crap?_; _does this help, or make finding solutions more difficult?_. Where that other answer fell, I'm not in a position to judge. Looks like some people who know the tech decided it was on the wrong side of the line. That doesn't mean that other things cannot be on the right side of it.

Comment: It's currently not locked.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the lock is on [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14534360/1188513), that I authored several years ago and, re-reading the question (and the *question* alone), doesn't strike me as a good question to ask at all, by today's standards, regardless of the self-answer.

Comment: Maybe the "how do I do X" == too broad could be clarified a bit to take the scale of "X" into account. For example, many of the top-voted git Q&A are "how do I do X", but I wouldn't call them too broad.

Answer (score 23):

Ok I am confused now.

As per [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-the-windows-10-calendar-in-vba-excel), it is encouraged to ask and answer your own question. In my opinion, It helps to spread knowledge. They are lot of people who can actually benefit from it.

The objective was to **help** the VBA community by providing a solution. VBA unfortunately doesn't have a free control for choosing date and time.

Some people assume that the datepicker and msCalendar are VBA controls. They are mistaken. They (datepicker and msCalendar) are VB6 controls which are not freely distributed. You need to register mscal.ocx or mscomct2.ocx or mscomctl.ocx to use these.

Now if I share some knowledge to make our lives easier by providing an alternative then is that a NO NO?

Now, I am not worried about the downvotes but if the question needs to be closed as `Too Broad` or something else then there is a problem with my understanding and I should know about it.

Is it not advisable to help the community by providing solutions to common problems then maybe I should stop proactively sharing what I know with the community?

I have updated the question. Hope it makes more sense now as to why that post is important for the VBA community. If not leave a comment below that post and we can take it from there.

Comment: Your question has to meet the same standards as a question that is not being asked for the sole purpose of self answering it at the same time.

Comment: I declined your flag to delete the question, and undeleted your answer. That kind of "pack up my toys and go home" action is both inappropriate and extremely premature. The question has just been brought up for discussion here on Meta as a candidate for re-opening. At a minimum, you should let that discussion play out a bit before deciding to take drastic action. Frankly, even if the question stays closed, it and the answer should not be deleted because they both add value to the community. Don't play a martyr here. We have disagreements about content and scope all the time. It's not personal.

Comment: `..they both add value to the community...` Doesn't look like it... @CodyGray: BTW Sorry just saw your comment. I had already deleted it. As far as that question is concerned, I am simply disgusted with the attitude towards the entire thing. I have already given up on that post. The community can feel free to do whatever it wants with that post... I am done with sharing knowledge...

Comment: I don't know why you're seeing such a strong negative attitude. The question and answer both received a large positive score in the very short time they were posted. Then, the question got closed. Okay, kinda not so fun. But then, someone raised an issue on Meta, asking why it got closed and wondering if we should re-open it. So, someone thought your question good enough and the answer useful enough that it was worth *fighting for*. That should be encouraging to you. As I said, we have disputes about the site's scope all the time. Please don't be disgusted about it. We appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @CodyGray - Can you explain why you locked the post? I disagree that it should be locked, and feel that you should have posted an answer for locking it. Especially given that your lock prevents reopen votes, and was timed as it was closed.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I for one think that while the format for your post could use improvement, it seems like good content. Please don't let this specific situation dissuade you from contributing.

Comment: @Travis The message there and the comments here are adequate explanation. There was a content dispute. I agree locking is not ideal, but deletion is worse while we’re trying to have a discussion about it. Frankly, I’m not especially persuaded by the argument that it needs to be unlocked so we can have a parallel close-reopen war with this Meta discussion. Just make the arguments here, where you can explain your thinking. It is not a permanent lock.

Comment: Thank you SiddharthRout for your numerous and immensely valuable contributions to the VBA tag - @CodyGray if that Q&A is off-topic, then I hereby request that [this Q&A of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14534360/1188513), which is one of my top-voted posts across the entire network, *and* my most viewed question on SO, receives the same treatment.

Comment: @CodyGray: I would like to give it one last try. Could you please unlock the post so that I can edit the question to make it more "sensible"?

Comment: @CodyGray: There is also an invalid edit `..and so only work with 32-bit versions of Office...` in that post. This is not true. My content is ready so I just need couple of minutes to update the question.

Comment: Happy to unlock, as long as you and other Meta folks aren't going to engage in a delete war. I seem to have given the impression to you and @Mathieu (at least, perhaps others) that I have a problem with this question. I don't. I think it's totally fine and on-topic. See [Optimizing for Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) for an explanation of why.

Comment: @CodyGray: Understood

Comment: @CodyGray: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The self-answer portion is irrelevant. And it has a good answer, which is also irrelevant.

The issue I have with this is that if we leave the question open as-is, people will feel free to ask tutorial questions and point to this as evidence that we're somehow playing favorites ("You let a 120k user post this but not a 10 rep user!") or that we're inconsistent.

> So how do we create that in VBA Excel?

I close a dozen of these every week. People want tutorials **all the time** and then complain when it's closed. Then you get the rift of Always Helpers (answer it! never close anything!) vs Curators (do we really want to encourage this kind of thing?)

I think what the OP is trying to do is good, but it needs to avoid being a simple "How I do this in X language?" question.

## Could it be fixed?

I think this would be better asked as such

> Unlike in VB6, there exists no native calendar widget in VBA. The only widgets I can find are very environment-dependent; they require registering mscal.ocx or mscomct2.ocx and so only work with 32-bit versions of Office.
>
> ```
> Some Code here using these OCX files
> ```
>
> Is there some way to do this in native [some language here] without those files?

We're no longer trying to set up a tutorial, we're asking a practical programming question, with code that works, but only with a paid MS library. Such a question avoids the tutorial problem.

Comment: Two issues with your fixed version: the code using the OCX files would be _completely irrelevant_ (and is present in the linked question anyway); and your final sentence is also meaningless (since it's VBA (**not VB6**; like Java and JavaScript) and, native or otherwise, it isn't capable of doing anything like VB6 without some seriously shaky hacks). Other than that, it seems to be the content of my edit (which has received 3 downvotes so far), with some fluff removed. Can you improve upon it otherwise?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The reason I didn't make that edit myself is that it not only do I not have said code (he implies another question has is but I'm not sure), but I would be changing the meaning of the question. The OP really needs to make this change since he understands what he's trying to get at. And I'm not a VB guy, just trying to offer a constructive example. Disregard the minutiae if I get them wrong ;)

Comment: The thing is, ignoring the minutia, your proposed edit is just removing everything after the first paragraph and adding some hypothetical irrelevant code (which would just be a codey way of inserting a control – a task usually accomplished via the UI – which would still have the environment issues); I don't see how it's an improvement to be blunt. The rest of the answer is great!

Comment: While I admire your optimism, I kinda feel that asking for tutorials is part of the background noise of The Internet; I don't think anything we do will reduce folks *asking* for them because almost by definition the folks asking either haven't searched at all or lack the vocabulary to find anything remotely close to what they're seeking - IOW, folks don't start out to write wonderfully-detailed, specific questions and then, upon seeing tutorial requests, abandon that approach - they never get there to begin with. Agree with editing though.

Comment: So if there were some crummy broken code in there, it's magically on topic?

Comment: @Comintern no, neither the non-inclusion makes it off topic. It's several times more nuanced than that.

Answer (score 11):

tl;dr; This post should remain open.

---

In my opinion, this post is exceptionally controversial; it represents something that the site has gone back and forth on for a long time.

Namely, that questions regarding "how do I accomplish X" without showing an attempt are bad. However, the reason this is controversial is because that outlook is nuanced. Any time there is nuance, there is interpretation.

From one the most referenced discussions on this topic <sup>**[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210844/178816)**</sup>, the overall consensus was an issue with the OP either not being versed in the question they were asking, or not providing context for the issue being described.

> If we allowed "How can I do X using Y" type questions with no investment from the OP, we would be creating an environment rich for abuse by help vampires. It is for the benefit of the site as a whole, rather than the OP, that we should be asking the OP to show us what they've already tried. -JDB <sup>**[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210844/178816)**</sup>

This is not the situation here though. While the question in original form did contain some preamble, it was very clear as to not only the context of the issue but the overall grasp of the issue being presented.

I do not think that questions should be closed solely because the OP is describing an issue which requires the creation of a solution. There are related issues with questions asking for such things though, which I understand, but this instance is *not* one of them.

As Shog9 states from the same previous discussion <sup>**[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210844/178816)**</sup>

> A reasonable question needs:
>
> 1. Context!
> 2. A clear statement of the problem!
> 3. An explanation for why the obvious solution (if one exists) didn't work.

This question has context, it is about using a calendar in vba excel. It has a clear problem, the calendar doesn't always exist. It has an explanation of what would normally work for inclusion, and why that wasn't a solution in this case.

Too Broad is a close reason which is often used for questions which people disagree should exist here, and as a result the post is pigeonholed into that. This post does not meet the criteria of Too Broad, and as such should simply be reopened. It has a specific problem, there is a clear way of identifying a solution, and there are not multiple questions being asked.

Simple, to the point, questions have been very productive so long as they are on topic. The main goal here is producing useful content that stands the test of time. Even if it is simple in nature, it can still be useful to millions of people: [Convert int to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string)

There is also a large history of self answered posts being encouraged here **<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/),[3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking),[4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)</sup>**, even Jeff Atwood created one which reads very similarly to the one we are examining (albeit on Super User); he also wrote a blog post **<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)</sup>** explicitly requesting this type of content creation.

This process is something we should encourage, especially from experienced users in the community. While it may be common to see a new user post a question about $ not being defined, and then self answer it with "oh, all you need to do is include jQuery", in general that is not the type of posts experienced users create.

I once had a rather involved discussion **<sup>[5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)</sup>** on this topic several years ago as well, because I got tired of seeing questions simply asking for us to do all the work. To note, that is not what is happening here. Irregardless of that though, Shog framed the issue rather well.

> I've become increasingly pessimistic over the years that this problem can be solved by a close reason. No, pessimistic is misleading; I'm straight-up convinced that closing is the wrong tool for the job here.
> At every turn, attempts to solve this problem have resulted in useful questions being closed without actually doing anything for the problem of obscure one-off requirement-dumps. -Shog9 **<sup>[5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)</sup>**

As a community which is oriented as content first, to me it makes no sense to close or delete this question. While the general class of questions may exhibit problems, that is just because the generalization casts such a wide net. Posts which are clear and contain quality content should not be discouraged.

---

<sub>1. [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding “A”s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/178816)</sub>
<sub>2. [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)</sub>
<sub>3. [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)</sub>
<sub>4. [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)</sub>
<sub>5. [Make it easier to close job shop “gimme teh codez” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)</sub>

Comment: This is an example of when jurisdiction is more important for SO then practical real-life value. I totally support closure/deletion of zero effort unproductive questions, but when such a question produces value for the community (especially in this case with a high-quality self-answer) practicality and added value should take priority over strict rule following.

Answer (score -1):

I've edited the question to read:

> Unlike in VB6, there exists no native calendar widget in VBA. The only widgets I can find are very environment-dependent; they require [registering `mscal.ocx` or `mscomct2.ocx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493134/5223757) and so only work with 32-bit versions of Office.
>
> [This calendar, using Userform and Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961), is incredibly basic and has a dissimilar UI to that of Windows 10.
>
> When I saw the Windows 10 calendar which popped up when I clicked on the date and time from the system tray, I could not help but wonder if we can replicate that in VBA.
>   This is what the calendar looks like in Windows 10:
>
> [obnoxiously-sized image]
>
> and this is how you interact with it:
>
> [image]
>
> **So how do we create that in VBA Excel?**

I think this is sufficiently question-like, though could still use improvement (not currently possible, due to the lock). Is this enough to qualify this for re-opening?

Comment: Meta isn’t different from main in the sense that whining about downvotes is unwanted. Yes, answers reflect your opinion. The best and easiest way to show agreement or disagreement with someone’s opinion is the downvote button. Comments are entirely optional, and in many cases, unnecessary, as on main. The vote says it all. If someone really wants to make a counter-argument, they should do it in an answer of their own, not a comment anyway. And yes, there was a bit of a delete war. See edit history and comments to the OP’s answer here on Meta. Will definitely unlock after some Meta discussion.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think this is the third(?) time I've been cross about a moderation decision that turned out to be completely justified, with no times it wasn't; I'll pay attention to this pattern in future.

Comment: I have no idea. I don’t keep score. :-) Also, if there was an attitude implied in my edit comment, it’s because I was honestly very surprised to see someone I respect editing a bold downvote rant into an answer. You and the crew have done a fantastic job over on Retrocomputing. I usually know what I’m doing, but don’t raise expectations too high. :-)

Answer (score -4):

Okay, here's another take.

Self-answered posts like this that present a piece of working code, are hard to fit into SO's scope: if we ignore the fact that Q+A being posted together is vastly different than asking "How do I do X?" and expecting someone else to answer that (IOW if we ignore the bulk of the effort that goes into such posts, which is completely unfair IMO, but I'm setting that aside for now), then indeed it looks like we're accepting behavior from high-profile users that we don't accept from new users.

The *question* is a pretext for the *answer*, and the answer is prompting feedback in the form of comments, which is prompting further code improvements.

There's a Stack Exchange site that's literally *dedicated* to *exactly* that purpose: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

The answer could be a CR question, presenting a working solution to a common problem. On CR, reviewers post answers that suggest improvements upon the OP, and it's not uncommon for the code being reviewed to also exist on GitHub, where the feedback from CR answers is incorporated (the original CR question must remain unchanged, else that's *answer invalidation*).

This solution:

- Gives the OP a high-visibility Stack Exchange platform to share their code and knowledge;
- No "pretext question": on CR the question *is* what has been presented here as an answer;
- Makes valuable feedback and alternative implementations be provided as votable answers, instead of noisy comments.

The only CR requirement that's implicit (though, easily made explicit), is that by putting up their solution on CR, the OP is asking the community to improve that code in any way possible, be it readability, maintainability, extensibility, reusability, etc. Note that Code Review posts have *double* the maximum number of characters of a Stack Overflow post.

Comment: So....you're proposing a migration to Code Review?

Comment: Wouldn't that make everyone happy? I'm saying there's absolutely a way to make this on-topic on CR. Migrating? No. It's the *answer* that needs to be a CR post, the pretext question is irrelevant, as are the edits and multiple versions. What I'm saying is that CR is a perfect platform to present a working solution and get community feedback on it.

Comment: I'd have no issues with that.  But that doesn't solve the problem of what to do with it here.

Comment: Well I've already made my case for what should be happening to it on SO, and it's apparently not a consensus. It depends what the consensus is. If it's "too broad" for SO, then CR will be happy to take it, that's all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Contrarily, I think the consensus is your first take. Not only is that the most upvoted response to this question, it's also the current status of the question on main (and backed up by not only a moderator but also a community manager). Code Review is a totally different site where code goes to die (as far as other people are concerned). No one goes to Code Review to find how to solve a programming problem; questions there are by nature too specific or too localized to be readily applied to other peoples' scenarios. Migrating a general how-to to CR would be a mistake IMO.

Comment: @TylerH looking at the views on my OOP Battleship CR posts, I have to agree with that. Still a take worth considering IMO.

Comment: I think this is appropriate in theory, but in practice, I have never had a question from the Code Review Stack Exchange appear in my searches when I've been stuck on something I'm working on, or at least not before any of the results that lead me to solve my issue. As I'm doing my research, Stack Overflow is frequently the place where I find people have had similar issues to what I'm dealing with, and keeping it here increases visibility to anyone searching for this kind of a solution. I'm afraid if it gets moved to Code Review, it'll just sit there ignored for all eternity.

Comment: @DavyM that's the thing, when you are looking for solutions, you look for the specific things you want to do, CR questions aren't "specific things", they have tons of context and non-generic stuff.

Comment: @DavyM you've never searched for "fizzbuzz in x86 assembler" then ;-)

Comment: FWIW, after seeing that the entire "thread" has devolved into a "forum discussion" about optimizing the "answer" I have to agree with you. In its current form it simply does not belong here. And, besides being "too broad" that original question also should be looked at as "requesting code, software, libraries" purely based on this "forum discussion" it has generated.

Comment: Fizzbuzz questions on SO? Really?

Comment: @Braiam on CR. Keep up. Point being, if you're seaeching for a working implementation of anything from FizzBuzz to a Tic-Tac-Toe game, you'll easily find it on CR. It's just a different search. Want SO results? Look for problems. Want CR results? Look for solutions.

Answer (score -5):

It seems that the whole issue here is that people are confused. But lets step back and point out the obvious:

- Who, other than the OP, could take a stab answering the question?
- Why would an answer needs to skirt the character limits by linking to external resources?
- Why does it needs to be a single question?

Now, I was under the impression that on Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general, each question is held to the same standards everywhere. This question, is too daunting, that no one would *ever* try to answer it. Heck, the other answer is just a comment suggesting improvements on the behemoth that is the other answer, but it couldn't post the complete suggestion. This is unfair to other potential answerers, since if they don't implement the complete solution, they will not be able to answer this question *at all*, and I'm sure that there are many ways to implement a calendar on any language (looks at the desktop to see at least 4 implementations of a calendar).

The question not only asks to all potential answerers to implement all the required parts to make the calendar works, but they should do so while not hitting the character limit. This is the clearest indication that the question isn't optimized for Stack Exchange format. When you are hitting those limits, you are adding too much content. But when it's necessary, not optional, to address the question fully that is an alert that the question needs to be downsized into more actionable parts.

Recently, I had to work with VBA, and one of the most important Q&A pairs which I was discussing with a peer was a question about how to implement a Access field to store and use a dictionary of values. That was as obvious "How to do X?" as it can get, and I found a powerful argument about how to actually solve X in a way that it doesn't causes pains, while my peer was about to implement another solution. The question wasn't closed as too broad, the answer didn't need me to scroll the screen, yet it was useful.

The potential solutions that this full implementation has for others is diminished by the sheer size of the project. If, for example, I was looking to implement a multilevel transition between different views, this question could have the answer I'm looking for, but since I'm not implementing a calendar I will never find the answer. I would most likely ask a question about my model and constrains which is useful to that specific programming problem. This question, despite the cool that looks and the effort invested, wouldn't be useful for anyone but OP and whoever happens to get a assignment on a course about implementing a calendar with VBA in Excel (which btw, I think a calendar without being able to add events to it, isn't useful).

Comment: The slight little issue is that, people ask about a calendar control rather often, and this answer is currently the only good alternative to "well use 3 textboxes and validate the input", and whether it's useful or not is subjective anyway, and that's why the voting buttons exist. And I'll take the dare for another implementation and complete answer. This is nothing compared to the 64K characters allowed on Code Review. Hmm. The answer *would* make a great CR post, now that I think of it.

Comment: Anyway I consider that question very much equivalent to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14534360/1188513), and the views and the votes seem to indicate that posts like these *are* extremely useful.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon None of that changes that we're exhibiting a massive double standard by reopening this; anyone else, *anyone else* asking this would have it automatically closed as too broad.  That doesn't set a good example for how new users are supposed to ask questions at all.  Is the question useful?  Undoubtedly.  But self answering doesn't give anybody a free pass.  The question *has* to stand on it's own, and the question is incredibly broad.  I don't think anyone denies that at all.

Comment: Then the self-answering feature needs to go, and that question and the one I linked to, and a bunch of others, need to go as well, because consistency. Unless... Unless instant self-answering *does* make a difference? Or turning the question into a broken attempt at solving the problem would suddenly make it fine? What do you suggest? Closing & locking it? And that's a win how? See my own answer here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I don't know.  I just know there needs to be some sort of consistency, because dollars to donuts, someone's going to use it to defend their massively overbroad question, and to be honest, they'll be right to do so.  We are encouraged to self answer, but none of that changes that all questions have to be held to the same standard.

Comment: You're missing the point I'm making [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380145/1188513), that there's a major difference between asking "how do I do X?" *while expecting someone else to answer*, and asking "how do I do X?" *and answering it **at the same time** as you ask the question*. One takes 30 seconds and zero effort to post, the other well over an hour, and that's not counting all the work that needs to go into just preparing that post.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon No, I'm not missing it.  I'm *actively* ignoring it, because what answers there are *irrelevant* to the scenario.  A question is a *question*.  It *has* to stand on it's own.  Look at that question, and ask yourself, "If this was asked by a 1 rep user, how would I treat it?"

Comment: I've already adressed that, and you chose to ignore it. I've nothing else to add. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The fact that the answer you're defending so assiduously is still an actively moving target kind of makes my point for me.  SO is being treated as a project space for this calendar control, not as a self contained question and answer.  *Any* other asker would have that question closed, and rightfully so.  There's no denying that the answer is useful.  It's just that we're trying to jam a square peg into a round hole.  The continually updated answer and using the comments as feature improvement requests is a code smell.

Comment: @fbueckert And on the other hand, if SO is being treated as simply a space for correcting newbie syntax errors and broken code, then it has lost a large amount of usefulness to me. Consider [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380116/creating-the-windows-10-calendar-in-vba-excel-can-we-allow-broad-and-useful-ca/380154#comment669879_380116). If the (sarcastically) suggested edit were made, does that magically meet your standard now?

Comment: @Comintern I'm not sure there is, because the question itself is a massive ask, all by itself.  Adding broken code won't salvage it, because at it's heart, it's asking for too much.  As a sidenote, I don't think the sarcasm and snark add constructively to the discussion. I get that you have some sour grapes with how this went down.  I wish there was a better way that we could accommodate everybody, and still be consistent.  I think we can maintain standards higher than, "Better than most of the junk we see in [tag:vba]".  That's a very low bar.

Comment: @fbueckert "Better than most of the junk we see in vba" is hardly a bar at all, granted. But if posting broken code to answer with the non-broken code is the standard, then the bar isn't being set on the question - it's being set on the usefulness of SO to me as a professional. If SO is a solely place for novice coders to post trashy code, then it has lost a great deal of usefulness to me.

Comment: @Comintern And that's a valid point; you're not the only one who hates being treated as a help desk.  I can't deny that SO has helped me immensely in my professional career, but much of that comes from piecemeal issues, not whole projects disguised as a question.  Broken code in this case would be another code smell; an attempt to conform to the letter of the rules while entirely ignoring the spirit.  I've been racking my brain trying to find a way that makes this less broad, but...I'm not seeing one that would work that doesn't fundamentally kill the usefulness already here.

Comment: I feel like this question should be a git project or something, where it can be properly handled with a system meant to take ever changing code and resolving issues with it.  That would still be useful as a link to questions where a calendar control is needed.  Trying to jam that functionality into SO doesn't work very well at all, and while answers can be collaborative, it's not meant for whole projects.

Comment: @fbueckert Totally agree that there isn't a bright line - it depends on the context. If you flip the question around and make it "how can I load the VB6 date picker in Access x64 iwthout using Office 365 ", then it's not broad - the only answer is "You can't - it's a 32 bit library". I guess my standpoint is that if that were the question, answering with "You can't, but you can do this instead..." doesn't change the fact that the question has one "answer". Focusing on the semantics of the question as opposed to the problem domain puts pedantry on a higher plane than usefulness.

Comment: @Comintern Ehhhh.  I don't think classifying disagreement as pedantry is useful in any discussion.  If usefulness is all that mattered, we'd allow recommendations and opinionated questions, too.  But trying to build a repository requires us to have more exacting standards than, "eh, it's not quite up to our standards, but it's useful, so meh."  Your example question should ideally have a link to the repo, not use the answer as the repo itself.  Nor does it limit a calendar control to a single specific iteration with arbitrary requirements.

Comment: @fbueckert - You miss the point. I'm saying that conflating the way that a question is asked with how the broadness of the problem domain is what's pedantic. I'd consider "How can I load the VB6 date picker in Access x64 without using Office 365" to be quite specific.  The answer answers it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188358/discussion-between-fbueckert-and-comintern).

Comment: Let's not continue this in chat.and simply agree to disagree. I made my point, you made yours, so we can leave it at that.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm thinking [this take](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380164/1188513) can get everyone to agree.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So, because people ask garbage questions all the time, we should allow users based on rep and whether or not they already have an answer to get away with asking garbage questions.... lets not.. that's unfair and confusing to new users. Moderation of this site needs to be consistent.

Comment: @KevinB that is literally the exact opposite of what I'm saying. Quote: "If a 100K user asks a "how do I do X?" question **without it being instant self-answered**, then it **should be closed as too broad just like every other "how do I do X?"** only-answerable-with-a-tutorial question we see (and correctly vote to close) every day." and "Instant self-answers, **whether they're posted by a 100K rep or a 1-rep user**, are not too broad."

Comment: They absolutely are too broad. A good answer doesn't make a too broad question not too broad. The question should be able to stand on it's own. If it can't, it should be closed.

Comment: If we don't close it, we're just creating a double standard and setting up new users for failure by making it appear as though they can ask a too broad question and receive an awesome answer, only to find out that they're going to get downvoted to oblivion and have their question closed, likely pushing them into questing throttling as they try to figure out why.

Comment: @KevinB good. Only problem: that doesn't appear to be the consensus, and the most downvoted answer on this page is the ideal solution that treats these Q+A posts as "too broad" while keeping them on SE. So, what's the solution then, and what the hell is the "post Q+A" feature supposed to be used for?

Comment: there doesn't need to be a consensus. The rules are in place. If you don't like the rules, petition them to be changed.

Comment: @KevinB - If there doesn't need to be a consensus, I should probably stop voting and using meta then? Can you direct me to these "rules"?

Comment: The rules are, generally speaking, _created by_ the consensus which forms on Meta posts like this one.

Comment: @JoshCaswell but we aren't discussing the rule, but a question to which a rule is applied.

Comment: Again, the rules arise from discussing _instances_ in which they apply (or not).