# Is blog-style self-answering accepted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, self-answer

I'm aware that self-answering is a thing and that, when "asking a question" there is an option to "self-answer" right away.

But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637000/how-to-call-from-webassembly-websocket-api), which I ran into while recommending deletion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22197907):

- The question, if asked by someone who does not mean to answer it himself would surely have been deleted.
- As far as I know broad "how to do X" questions are not welcome on SO
- The first answer requires quite a bit of editing to reach SO's expected quality
- The second answer makes the whole thread look a bit like a "R&D blog" ...

Overall the whole thing looks weird...

> [image: "It's easy. Please see code in response."]

Ignoring the poor grammar and indecent formatting, would this user's approach of Stack Overflow be fit for the site? I'm tempted to flag the question but, considering it has eight upvotes on both the question and the first answer I guess people actually found it useful?

edit: As per Opa's request and Cody's memory, here is the original question's full text:

> It's easy. Please see code in response.

Comment: What eight people upvoted *that*? I'd be suspicious of vote fraud...

Comment: There is nothing normal about the way that Q+A got voted on, pretty easy to see from the user's Reputation tab.  Flag a moderator to have a look at it.

Comment: Didn't we [just talk about this yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380116/creating-the-windows-10-calendar-in-vba-excel-can-we-allow-broad-and-useful-ca)?

Comment: Examples like this would have been a good fit for Documentation. Alas.

Comment: Why is it so hard for people to pretend they're on Jeopardy?

Comment: @CodyGray Writing good questions is *hard*.  Even for people who can do it, it takes a lot of time and effort.  People are lazy, and so aren't willing to spend the time.  They're even *less* likely to take the time to write a good question when they aren't trying to get someone to answer them, and instead are only doing it, "because the site forces me to." without considering for how much value is added by having a well written question.

Comment: Wow. I mean, it's not even *trying*. This *reductio ad absurdum* Q+A (for whatever value of Q there is in there) demonstrates a glaring loophole in the position I was defending, that I'm quite ashamed of not seeing coming when I posted my answer in last night's meta on a similar topic. If that OP posted this Q+A after reading my answer from yesterday, "I'm sorry" is all I can say here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I had not read yesterday's related post when I posted my own question, but I have now read your answer to it. I want to say that I agree with the point of view you defend and that your answer never indicated that the "self-answer" posts were exonerated from following the rules applying to the other posts. Namingly: be clear, well written, and so on.

Comment: @CodyGray could you or someone else edit this question to post the original text?  Everyone keeps talking about how this is a bad example of a self answer, but I can't see the question or answer.

Comment: The entire text of the question, @opa, was *"It's easy. Please see code in response."*

Comment: Sorry, I should have added a screenshot of the original thread for reference. Edited my post.

Comment: @CodyGray Wait, Stack Overflow isn't a subtle homage to [Celebrity Jeopardy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch_hoYPPeGc)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The thing about self-answered posts is that it still has to be a *question* and *answer*.  The OP there didn't actually ask a *question*, so it would still be subject to question quality scrutiny.

Tricky thing there is that people *might* have found it valuable.  If the question can be rewritten as an actual *question* maybe it could be saved.  Not sure I see much utility in that, though.

Comment: The question is in the title, not the text. Which is often a problem...

Comment: Right, I can't think of a single good SO question I saw where the title was a sufficient description of the problem/question. The question in the OP makes me think, "Call? Call what? And why?" (It's generally good to say WHY you're asking something because someone may have an alternative solution to the problem other than the question you're asking.)